# Error de Jquery al Imprimir un HTML en el body

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Estoy utilizando `ajax` para solicitar información a la base de datos de un `input` en el `body`

```
 <form id="busqueda1" method="POST" action="consultar.php">
 <input type="text"  id="busquedaC"   class="form-control cajabusqueda" 
  name="rifC" placeholder="J-000000-0"><br>
 <button type= " button" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-sm pb_btn- 
  smoothscroll"    id="buscarC">Buscar</button></form>
```

Para ser insertada en una tabla al momento de recibir respuesta mediante el `AJAX`

```
 <table id= "tabladatos" class="table table-bordered">
     <div class="btn-group-sm">
         <td><button id="editar" class=" btn-block btn btn-outline-warning btn- 
               sm " data-toggle="modal" data- 
                      target="#modaleditarClients">Editar</button></td>
    <?php if ($_SESSION['TipoOp']== 1) {  ?>
              <td><button  id="Borrar"class=" btn-block btn btn-outline-danger 
                  btn- sm" 
                 data-toggle ="modal" data- 
                 target="#modalBorrarClientes">Borrrar</button>
             </td>
    <?php  } ?>
  </div>    
</table>
```

Este es el `Script` que recibe lo consultado desde el `form` que está descrito mas arriba

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                  $("#buscarC").click(function() {
                     var datos = $("#busqueda1").serialize();

                   $.ajax({

                      type:"POST",
                      url:"consultar.php",
                      data: datos,
                      success:function(request){

                           var js=JSON.parse(request);

                       }

                   });


                   $('#tabladatos').html( '<tr><th>nombre</th>'+
                                '<th>rif</th>'+
                                '<th>R.Legal</th>'+
                                '<th>email</th>'+
                                '<th>instagram</th></tr>'+
                                '<tr>'+
                                '<td>'+js["nb_empresa"]+'</td>'+
                                '<td></td>'+
                                '<td></td>'+
                                '<td></td>'+
                                '<td></td>'+
                                '</tr>'

                                );

                   return false;
               });
           });


       </script>
```

El error se genera al momento de insertar el `HTML`, se abre el documento `PHP` con el resultado de la consulta solicitada por `ajax`, esto sucede si trato de imprimir el objeto que contiene los datos recibido del `PHP` todo el `Script` lo he checado mediante `alert` en la pantalla para ver que se esté enviado y recibiendo de manera adecuada la información.

```
<?php

session_start();

$conexion = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','crmasgmultiplex');

$rif = $_POST['rifC'];

$sql = "select nb_empresa, rif_empresa, repre_legal_empresa, 
       mail_empresa, instagram_empresa from usuarios where rif_empresa = '$rif'";


$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

if($consulta){


while($resultados = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

       $datos=$resultados;      

}

//echo $resultados;

echo json_encode($datos);


}else{

       echo"error al conectar a base de datos";
}
?>
```

Comment: Que te llega en la variable `request` del `success` de tu ajax?

Comment: {"nb_empresa":"ASGMULTIPLEX","rif_empresa":"0","repre_legal_empresa":"Gerardo Herrera","mail_empresa":"gherrera@asgmultiplex.com","instagram_empresa":"@asgmultiplex"}

Comment: Esa es la informacion en la DB  en formato de Json, incluso la puedo imprimir si la llamo por el Key de cada Una

Comment: Intenta agregar tu HTML en las llaves del `success:function(request){}`

Comment: El código donde cambias los datos (`$('#tabladatos').html...`) está fuera del success. Eso significa que se ejecutará antes de que recibas los datos y no va a funcionar. Mueve ese código a dentro del success y prueba de nuevo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mueve tu generador de html en la función success, ya que este se ejecutará una vez tu response tenga alguna respuesta.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $("#buscarC").click(function() {
        var datos = $("#busqueda1").serialize();
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"consultar.php",
          data: datos,
          success:function(request){
             var js=JSON.parse(request);
             $('#tabladatos').html( '<tr><th>nombre</th>'+
            '<th>rif</th>'+
                            '<th>R.Legal</th>'+
                            '<th>email</th>'+
                            '<th>instagram</th></tr>'+
                            '<tr>'+
                            '<td>'+js["nb_empresa"]+'</td>'+
                            '<td></td>'+
                            '<td></td>'+
                            '<td></td>'+
                            '<td></td>'+
                            '</tr>'

                            );

               return false;
           });
          }
         });

       });


   </script>
```